# MPRemoteCommandCenter SomeTimes doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, superpowered, mpremotecommandcenter, mpmedialibrary

I have a music player that uses [Superpowered](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-iOS-Linux-Windows-tvOS-macOS-Interactive-Audio-Platform) as an audio player. I followed this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/MPRemoteCommandSample/Listings/MPRemoteCommandSample_AppDelegate_swift.html) to implement a player widget. However, the widget sometimes shows up and many times doesn't.
**I want the player widget to show up whenever there is audio playing.**

**[RemoteCommandManager.swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/MPRemoteCommandSample/Listings/Shared_Managers_RemoteCommandManager_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017322-Shared_Managers_RemoteCommandManager_swift-DontLinkElementID_21)**: (From the article)

**AppDelegate.swift**:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Initializer the `RemoteCommandManager`.
        remoteCommandManager = RemoteCommandManager()

        // Always enable playback commands in MPRemoteCommandCenter.
        remoteCommandManager.activatePlaybackCommands(true)

        // Setup AVAudioSession to indicate to the system you how intend to play audio.
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        }
        catch {
            print("An error occured setting the audio session category: \(error)")
        }


        return true
}
```

**PlayerManager.swift**:

```
func play() {
    let _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    superpowered.play()
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed the following scenario:

If an iTunes track is playing (i.e the player widget is present) then I play an audio file using my app, the player widget changes so that it shows info of my app.

My guess is that when I activate the audio session, the player widget switches from iTunes to my app. However, when the player widget is not present, activating the audio session fails to present it.

Answer (score 0):

try setting up the audioSession to active in AppDelegate, just above the returning the function, 
*func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions....*

```
// Set the AVAudioSession as active.  This is required so that your application becomes the "Now Playing" app.
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: [])
    }
    catch {
        print("An Error occured activating the audio session: \(error)")
    }
```

and check if that helps.